Does 'First Mention' Override Uniqueness in Some Cases When Choosing Articles?
I'm revisiting a topic that I believe hasn't received a proper answer yet: choosing between the indefinite and the definite articles when a modifier is used in a noun phrase.
Please see the following example, created by me (the context is a written piece of fiction, though this isn't part of a completed work):

Jake thought back to a/the man whose life he'd taken when he was just a boy.

The background of the sentence is this: Jake took the life of only one man when he was boy, and the reader has never been introduced to this man, making the noun phrase new information.
What is more appropriate in this context, 'a' or 'the'? And why?
Research
I've recently been reading Articles by Roger Berry (which is part of Collins Cobuild English Guides) because I've been struggling to find a reliable source that explains this nuanced area of article usage, and this was said to be the most comprehensive piece of writing on the topic.
Sadly, in the book, the author doesn't directly address my query, though he does provide information that, with reinforcement by others, could offer an acceptable conclusion.
On the topic of first introduction, he says this:

You usually use the indefinite article when you are introducing a particular thing (or person) into a conversation or text for the first time and you cannot assume that your listener or reader knows which particular thing you are talking about.

The author also comments on qualification, saying this:

The definite article is ... used with nouns when ... the phrase or clause following the noun ... indicates which thing the noun refers to.

He gives this example:

... to get back to the hotel where he was staying.'

He also says this:

Superlative adjectives tend to occur with the definite article.

My Conclusions
The superlative example is quite cut and dried, in my opinion, but the use of qualification seems less so. We've established in my example that the man in question is unique, and this is made clear by the relative clause beginning with 'whose'. Jake never took the life of anyone else when he was a boy; this is a fact that I want to make clear. Based on what's said in the book Articles regarding qualification, shouldn't that mean we use 'the'?
On the flip side, if the reader hasn't been introduced to the man before, even with the relative clause, using 'the' sounds odd to my ears. Does that mean that 'when ... you cannot assume that your listener or reader knows which particular thing you are talking about' overrides any modification, even if said modification makes the noun phrase unique? I like to think so, but I'm also conscious that it makes it sound as though this man is one of multiple; the indefinite article gives the impression he is just one of a category containing others whose lives Jake took.

Check your verb: to think back on suggests this is not the first time he has thought of it. So, it's a specificity. She thinks back on the life she led prior to marriage. Not a new thing. Therefore, specific: the.

@Lambie, he could’ve thought about it prior to the narrative and, therefore, prior to the reader knowing about it, so I’m not sure I follow, unfortunately. Your example, I think, necessitates ‘the’, because ‘a life she led’ isn’t very idiomatic. It’s possible, I guess, but I’ve never heard anyone say that phrase with an indefinite article.

She thinks back on a life she had imagined leading. That life, a life led in the safety of a peaceful place was what she longed for.

So are you introducing the topic, or mentioning it in passing? (Also, there are many cases when both would do, but without knowing the context I'm not making any claims.)

You use the definite article when referring to a known item.
So if the story has previously established that Jake had killed someone, you should write "the man whose life he'd taken".
If this is the first mention of Jake having killed someone, you can use either the definite or indefinite article. It's a style choice, and I think "the" is used if you want to focus attention on the victim.
After this first mention the victim is known, so you use "the" in all subsequent mentions.

That the reader has not heard of the man Jake killed is not necessarily relevant, since narration in a fiction, even when it is third person,  can indirectly reveal the thought of characters being talked about. Jake knows who the man is.
To say "a man he killed" is to talk about it from an external vantage point. To say "the man he killed" is to talk about it from Jake's private vantage point when the reader has not heard about it until that moment.
To invoke that private vantage point is surely not inappropriate when the passage is telling the reader what Jake is thinking!
You don't even have to tell the reader what Jake is doing, that he is thinking back. You can just have him do it, without any sort of crutch for the reader. It can be a complete non sequitur:

The man he killed had smelled of tar and whiskey.


If the writer decides to use 'a' to introduce the noun phrase from an external POV, does that have the effect of creating a category of people Jake killed? I think that's part of where my confusion has arisen. For example, in the Witcher series, there's this noun phrase: '... a chestnut-haired sorceress who had appeared in Brokilon in a flash of magic with a wounded man', but this is clearly a unique entity. Another example is this: '... a wonderful man in Chicago who had turned her whole life around and who had, by some benign magic, been able to transform his wife's simple talent ...'

"a man he killed in his youth" does not make Jake a repeat murderer but leaves open that possibility of other victims in his youth. But "the man he killed in his youth",  also leaves open the possibility of other murders later  in his life, and of murders of women and children in his youth.
